# Confusion with initializing char[]

Tags: c

Please see the following code:

```
char h[256];
    h[0]=NULL;
    if(h!=NULL)
    {
        printf("It doesn't show NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("It shows NULL\n");
    }
```

and also the following:

```
char h[256];
        if(h!=NULL)
        {
            printf("It doesn't show NULL\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("It shows NULL\n");
        }
```

and also the following:

```
 char h[256];
h[0]='\0';
            if(h!=NULL)
            {
                printf("It doesn't show NULL\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("It shows NULL\n");
            }
```

In every case the `char* h` doesn't have NULL. Why is it the case? Isn't it suppose to have NULL as I'm not storing anything there? And if it's not the case, how I can I make sure that it contains nothing but NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`h[0]` is not the same as `h`.  `h[0]` is the first character in the array; `h` is the array itself (which decays to a pointer in this situation).

Try this:

```
char h[256];
h[0]=NULL;
if(h[0]!=NULL)
{
    printf("It doesn't show NULL\n");
}
else
{
    printf("It shows NULL\n");
}
```

Note also that you probably shouldn't be using `NULL` in this situation.  `NULL` is for pointers; you want `'\0'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're allocating the `char[]` array on the stack it cannot be `NULL`. `h` will always point to a valid location within memory, so your checks **must** fail.

If you want to initialize your array without data you should use

```
char h[256] = {'\0'};
```

`'\0'` is the `NUL` character which is not the same as `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your condition is `if(h != NULL)` which means you're actually comparing address of `h` which certainly will not `NULL`. Had it been `if(*h != NULL)`, first and third case would definitely execute `else` part. As of second part, it will be containing some garbage value at h[0], so by chance if its `0`, it will execute `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

The definition

```
char h[256]
```

means *h* is an array. An array can't be *NULL*. An array is an area in memory storing a sequence of values.

You are somehow confusing *h* with a *pointer*.

Even if it was a pointer, the value of a pointer is not the same as the value of the *thing pointed at*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if(h!=NULL)
```

Why don't you use

```
if(h[0]!=NULL)
```

As you are initializing the first element of the array as null, not the array itself!
To make sure that the elements are null use

```
for(i=0; i<h.length ; i++)
 h[i]=NULL;
```

or use '\0' instead of NULL

As to why h is not NULL
try printing h
in java, the following would return a @....... value, which is basically the location the variable is pointing. (not null!)

```
System.out.println(c);
```

( long time since used c, so don't know if you can do similar thing in c)